# Firefox - Set capability not working

Tags: firefox, config, capability

I want to block image and Javascript from third-part on load, and edit user.js in profile folder to merge with pref.js when Firefox startup.
Here's my code in **user.js**:

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "noimage, nojs, nohrefs");
user_pref("capability.policy.nojs.sites", "http://abc.xyz https://abc.xyz");
user_pref("capability.policy.nojs.javascript.enabled", "noAccess");
user_pref("capability.policy.noimage.sites", "http://abc.xyz https://abc.xyz");
user_pref("capability.policy.noimage.permissions.image", 3);
user_pref("capability.policy.nohrefs.sites", "http://abc.xyz https://abc.xyz");
user_pref("capability.policy.nohrefs.HTMLAnchorElement.href", "noAccess");
```

I check it in **"about:config"** and see it show but it's didn't work in fact at anytime.

How to make it work ?

Reference links:

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=Category:Preferences&until=Places.frecency.unvisitedTypedBonus
- http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/ConfigPolicy.html

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for an answer, the capability.policy.nojsbroken.javascript.enabled is gone since Firefox 29, please refeer to [this answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1000843).